# I'm trying to make a Discord Rich Presence for a game called "Fate Stay Night" but codes aren't working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code and shell.exec(" ") command works but the other one isn't working. If i delete shell.exec(" ") other code works. How i fix this?

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = require('discord-rich-presence')('CLIENT-ID')
const shell = require('shelljs')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in`);
});

shell.exec("C:\\FateSN\\FateRealtaNua\\Fate.exe") 

client.updatePresence({
    state: 'Stay Night',
    details: 'Ultimate Edition',
    startTimestamp: 0,
    endTimestamp: 0,
    largeImageKey: 'pp',
    smallImageKey: 'fate',
    smallImageText: 'Stay Night',
    instance: true,
})```
````

Comment: shell.exec() runs code synchronously, so the script hangs until you close the game. Try `shell.exec("start C:\\FateSN\\FateRealtaNua\\Fate.exe")` instead. (note that you don't need the shelljs module for this, you can use node's child_process instead)

Answer (score 1):

Its Pretty Easy, Look At The Code Below:

```js
const RPC = require("discord-rpc");
const rpc = new RPC.Client({
    transport: "ipc"
});

rpc.on("ready", () => {
    
    rpc.setActivity({
        details: "", // Details!
        state: "", // State Of Your RPC Client
        startTimestamp: new Date(),
        largeImageKey: "", //  Name Of The Large Image You Uploaded In Assets
        largeImageText: "" // Text When Hovered On Large Image
        
        
    });
    
    console.log("Rich Presence Is Now Active, Check Your Discord!"); // A Message In Terminal When RPC Is Turned On.
});

rpc.login({
    clientId: "" // Your Client ID
})
```